# get the value of a row in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having problem getting the value of the row of my table using ajax and so far every time im getting its values its giving me nothing in return here is how i get it.

## select.php

```
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
       $output .= '  
            <tr>  
                 <td>'.$row["wmID"].'</td>  
                 <td class="first_name" data-id1="'.$row["userFirstname"].'" >'.$row["userFirstname"].'</td>  
                 <td class="last_name" data-id2="'.$row["userLastname"].'" >'.$row["userLastname"].'</td>  
                 <td class="payment" data-id3="'.$row["payment"].'" >'.$row["payment"].'</td>  
                 <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id4="'.$row["wmID"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">Remit</button></td>  
            </tr>  
       ';
  }
```

## edit.php

```
<?php  
include_once('../connection.php');
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_request SET isRemitted = 'Yes' WHERE wmID = '".$_POST['id']."'"; 

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_remit ('rAmount', 'rDate', 'rTime', 'wmID') VALUES 
('".$_POST['payment']."',$date,$time,'".$_POST['id']."')";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql) && mysqli_query($conn, $query))  
{  
  echo 'Payment Remitted' .mysqli_error($conn);  
}  else{
echo 'Rermittance failed' .mysqli_error($conn);  
}
?>
```

## ajax code for updating

```
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function(){  
       var id=$(this).data("id4");   
       var payment=$(this).data("id3");
       var firstname=$(this).data("id2");
       var lastname=$(this).data("id1");
       if(confirm("Is this really remitted?"))  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"edit.php",  
                 type:"POST",  
                 data:{id:id,payment:payment},  
                 dataType: "text",  
                 success:function(data){  
                      alert(data);  
                      fetch_data();  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
  });
```

Comment: hi in your page select.php where are the echo of your $output and same for the edit.php?

Comment: @headmax - you mean the output table sir?

Comment: i mean the echo json_encode($oupout) and the header("Content-type:application/json");

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: For the security use Filter Input from native PHP can simply protect your ... :)  http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php for the request SQL use PDO.

Comment: does your var id have a value ?

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez - Yes sir I'm getting a value for id.

Comment: the payment firstname and last name ?

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez - those 3 i'm not getting any.

Comment: try my answer i posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put all the data in the button to trigger the value

```
 <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id1="'.$row["userFirstname"].'" data-id2="'.$row["userLastname"].'" data-id3="'.$row["payment"].'" data-id4="'.$row["wmID"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">Remit</button></td>
```